# Hi, I'm wondering if someone can help me prove that if f is strictly monotone, then f is injective?

Tags: proof-verification

I'm wondering if someone can help me prove that if f is strictly monotone, then f is injective?

Comment: Suppose $f$ is not injective. That means there must exist distinct $a,b$ such that _____?

Comment: Do you know what are the definitions of monotone and injective?

Comment: Beware of the context... [Giving an example of a strictly monotone function which is not injective.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3743136)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, is it possible to have $f(a) < f(b)$ and *also* $f(a) = f(b)$?

strictly monotonically increasing [decreasing] means when ever $a < b$ then $f(a) < f(b)$ [$f(a) > f(b)$].

So if $a \ne b$ then either $a < b$ or $a > b$ and if $f$ is monotonic, either increasing or decreasing, then eithere $f(a) > f(b)$ or $f(a) < f(b)$.  In either case $f(a) \ne f(b)$.

Comment: You have to assume that the domain of $f$ is *totally* ordered.