# Giving an example of a strictly monotone function which is not injective.

Tags: solution-verification, relations, order-theory, monotone-functions

*The following question/task is from Taylor's, "Practical Foundations of Mathematics," page 175, ISBN 0 521 63107 6 hardback. I kind of answered it myself in typing this up, but I'll share it anyway so that others may benefit. [This Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=strictly%20monotone%2C%20not%20injective&p=1) indicates that it is new to MSE.*

### The Details:

From page 103, *ibid.* . . .

> **Definition 2.6.1:** A function $f:(X,<)\to(Y,\prec)$ between sets with binary relations is said to be *strictly monotone* if
> $$\forall x, x'.\, x'<x\implies f(x')\prec f(x).$$

(*NB:* The lack of $\in$ here is used throughout most of the book so far; I can't, for the life of me, figure out why - the answer is buried deep and forgotten long ago.)

### The Question:

> Give an example of a strictly monotone function which is not injective.

### My Attempt:

I want to show that there exists a strictly monotone $f:(X,<)\to(Y,\prec)$ such that there exist $a,a'\in X$ with $f(a)=f(a')$ but $a\neq a'$.

One idea is to picture a v-shaped lattice on three nodes as $(X,<)$, where $a$ and $a'$ occupy the top nodes; essentially: there exists a $b\in X$ with $b<a$ and $b<a'$, but $a\neq a'$ and are otherwise not comparable. Then I'll take $(Y,\prec)$ as the lattice with two nodes, say $y,y'\in Y$, where $$y=f(b)\prec y'=f(a)=f(a').$$

Now for all $x,x'\in X$, if $x<x'$, then $f(x)\prec f(x')$, so $f$ is indeed strictly monotone and, by construction, not injective.

> Is this correct?

Please help :)

Comment: Looks good to me!

Comment: Thank you, @Watercrystal :)

Comment: Nothing wrong with your approach, but perhaps even more simply, consider the case where the strict part of the relation on X is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a perfectly valid example. Good job!

---

*Mostly just posting this to get this out of the unanswered queue. Posting as Community Wiki in particular since I have nothing further to add.*

Comment: Does an injective function in order theory imply strictly monotone on partially ordered sets?